# characteristic cone of polyhedral

Tags: combinatorics, convex-optimization, linear-programming

> Let $$Q=\{x ∶ Ax ≤ b \}≠∅$$
>   If $Q = P + C$, where $P$
>   is a polytope and $C$ is a polyhedral cone, prove that
>   $$\{y|Ay ≤ 0\} = \{y|x + y ∈ Q, ∀ x ∈ Q\}$$
>   The cone $C = \{y|Ay ≤ 0\}$ is called the characteristic cone of Q.

this will be great if give me hint or Idea ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First, let us show that
$\{y \mid Ay \leq 0\} \subset \{y \mid x + y \in Q, \forall x \in Q\}$. 
Consider any $y_0$ for which $Ay_0 \leq 0$. Then
$$
x \in Q \Rightarrow Ax \leq b \Rightarrow Ax + Ay_0 \leq b + 0 \Rightarrow A(x+y_0) \leq b \Rightarrow x+y_0 \in Q.
$$
Next, let us show the reverse inclusion: 
$\{y \mid x + y \in Q, \forall x \in Q\} \subset \{y \mid Ay \leq 0\}$. 
Suppose for the sake of a contradiction that there exists $y_0$ such that
$x + y_0 \in Q, \forall x \in Q$ and a row $i$ of $A$ such that
$a_i^T y_0 > 0$. Let $m = \min \{b_i - a_i^T x \mid x \in Q\}$ with
$x_0 \in \arg \min\{ b_i - a_i^T x \mid x \in Q \}$. However, we know that 
$x_0 + y_0 \in Q$ which leads to the following contradiction:
$$ m \leq b_i - a_i^T (x_0 + y_0) = (b_i - a_i^Tx_0) - a_i^Ty_0 < m.$$
Hence, $\{y \mid x + y \in Q, \forall x \in Q\} \subset \{y \mid Ay \leq 0\}$.